# How to find ancestors of a merge in RTC command-line?

Tags: merge, rtc, revision-history

In RTC's gui, one can find a merge history graph by looking at the history tab of a given file.

[image]

How can I extract this from the command-line? The history subcommand gives very complete information, but nothing about the ancestors of a given file version.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=25912896#25912896: right... I never had to script that, so a question on https://jazz.net/forum/ might yield a better answer.